# jQuery If/Else statement, to check if element has class produces both results?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, responsive-design, enquire.js

I am using the [enquire.js](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) library to add JavaScript media queries into a site I am developing.

The issue happens when I initially load the website.

1. I resize into the 860px breakpoint, and toggle the nav. All works fine and as expected.
2. Then I resize past 860px.
3. And once again I resize back into the 860px enquire.js media query. The toggle nav outputs both console messages.

Any ideas?

```
   enquire.register("screen and (max-width:860px)", {

        match : function()
        {   
            nav_wrapper.removeClass('show').addClass('hide');

            nav_toggle.click(function()
            {
                if((nav_wrapper).hasClass('hide'))
                {
                    console.log('It\'s hidden');
                    nav_wrapper.removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log('It\'s opened up');
                    nav_wrapper.removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
                }

            });

        },

        unmatch : function()
        {
            nav_wrapper.removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
        },

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `match`, you're adding a **new** `click` handler (by doing `nav_toggle.click(function(){ ... })` again). They stack up, and they'll each get called. So after the first call to `match` you have one and probably get the behavior you expect. After the second call to `match`, you have two, and start getting the wrong behavior. After the third call to `match` you'd have three...

Looking at your `click` handler, there's no reason to do that, just hook it up once (presumably outside of `match`).

So for example:

```
// Hook up click **once**
nav_toggle.click(function() {
    if (nav_wrapper.hasClass('hide')) {
        console.log('It\'s hidden bud');
        nav_wrapper.removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
    } else {
        console.log('It\'s opedn up mate');
        nav_wrapper.removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    }

});

// Respond to screen width changes
enquire.register("screen and (max-width:860px)", {

    match: function() {
        nav_wrapper.removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    },

    unmatch: function() {
        nav_wrapper.removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
    },

});
```

---

Side note: I removed the unnecessary `()` around `nav_wrapper` in `if((nav_wrapper).hasClass('hide'))`.

Comment: Very thorough response! Thank you T.J.